# Disable a keyboard shortcut not defined in dconf

Tags: linux-mint, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

When I press `Super + Shift + S` keyboard shortcut, the Sound settings from the panel pops out as shown in the following picture. I want to disable this shortcut.

[image]

I could not find any defined keyboard shortcut in dconf, connected to above shortcut:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i '<super>'
```

Any idea how can I disable this shortcut in **Linux Mint 20.3**?